# Blocking favorite unless question has been upvoted

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I would like to hear your input on this, should we block the capacity to favorite a question unless the question has been upvoted? I see lots of questions which have more favorites than votes do you think this is bad?

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: I feel like the fact someone favorites a question should mean they think it is good, and a person who thinks it is good should upvote it.

Comment: But what if the user doesn't yet have [the privilege to upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up)? (See, also, the [MSE favorite questions faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/214632).)

Comment: I occasionally favourite a question because it's *bad,* and I want to keep an eye on it (especially if it's deleted).

Comment: As of this moment, this question has already been favorited by one user, but it does not have an upvote.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Now it does (it's almost a day later than your comment)!

Comment: @Bach, [people are talking](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30335) about your (needless) edit and they don't seem to like it. Please don't do that again.

Comment: @AlexM. Thank you for the heads up! In fact, I am not a native English speaker and I was using an online grammar checking plugin. I made this edit since ''Grammarly'' suggested it. No offense, I will try to avoid this kind of edits. Best~

Answer (score 16, accepted):

People favorite questions for all kinds of reasons that aren't synonymous with upvoting.  Sometimes the question is bad and the user wishes to keep an eye on it. Sometimes it's because the question might be good enough to answer if an edit is made, such as an "on hold" question. Sometimes one finds one of the answers exceptional, but doesn't think the question is all that good. This would be like insisting a user upvote a question before bookmarking it. I do not support your request.

Comment: Oh, I see, perhaps the name should be changed then, since "favorite" seems like something good to me, perhaps bookmark would be more appropriate

Comment: @Bananarama: I'm sure that in most cases a favorite question is a good one. If there were a way to have both "favorites" and "bookmarked" questions, I would do reorganize my lists, but it is not a pressing concern. At least not for me.

Answer (score 4):

I am one of the people who does this occasionally. One of my motives for roaming on our site is to search for material: nice questions that I can imagine turning into a homework problem, or into a contest question (junior high or high school level).

When I find such a question I will favorite it. As a kinda bookmark so that I can find it again later. If the OP has put the usual amount effort into it, sure, I will upvote. But upvoting a PSQ just doesn't feel right. In those cases my appreciation belongs to whoever composed the problem.

FWIW as of today my list of favorites runs into 18 pages. May be a quarter of them are of this material search -type. I dare not guess how many of those are without my upvote. At least one of them was deleted (by the OP).

Anyway, I oppose this suggestion. The star belongs to the question, the upvote to the asker.

Comment: just one questions, what is PSW

Comment: I seem to have caught the acronym bug. See [our local list](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3014/11619).