# Can you please give new users some time to breathe?

Tags: discussion, closing, new-users

I have just logged in on math.stack and I immediately see

> Can you guys please provide the answer? [closed]

and then I clicked and I realized that OP asked the question **5 minutes ago**

see

[image]

[image]

Is that ok ?

OP is a *new contributor* that does not even know how to use MathJax,  by judging the question seems like is a first year student (remember how lost one is in the first years) and by looking at his name (Japanese name) seems like it is not a native english speaker.

---

Note: Don't read my question like a rant (which means speak or shout at length in a wild, impassioned way) that was not the tone when I was writing it. Had I used mark like this one !!!! or ??? or other kind of comments, that'd have been different.

Comment: The point of closing the question is to give the OP a chance to improve it -- by looking up how to use MathJax, and in this case by providing sufficient context and writing *an actual question* there.  Closing it *is* giving them a chance to breathe, to borrow your title

Comment: @postmortes Maybe it's not big deal for native english speaker or maybe I am overreacting _but_ the word [closed] in bold doesn't looks welcome _at all_ and maybe it wouldn't be that bad after some time, but 5 minutes.. ?

Comment: .. and when the OP improves the question, it will never be opened again, for example because even improved, the question is of little interest.

Comment: @user486983 What would you suggest instead of "closed" then?  As there is actually no question there at all, just a statement, I think it would be fair to say that being open for 5 minutes is rather generous for something that doesn't even attempt to follow the rules of the site.  It has big problems that need to be addressed and by closing it we give the OP a chance to do that.  That impersonal message doesn't criticise, it simply says what needs to be improved.

Comment: @postmortes don't lie that closing is for improving a question, it is (for this particular question at least) is a step for deleting a question.

Comment: @postmortes Well is not that I have something against **Closed** unless is used in this specific cases and within 5 minutes. Maybe a [Temporarily on hold] would fit better. I agree that OP didn't follow the rules of the site but there is a really high chance that was not intentional. Again, you need to take into account his background: is a new contributor that does not even know how to use MathJax and by judging the question seems like is a first year student + his name is Japanese i.e. a probability that is not a native english speaker

Comment: @kludg Closing is a necessary step for deletion but, AFAIK, not a sufficient one.  If you only vote to close because you intend to see the question deleted that is your prerogative, but it seems unfriendly to pretend that it's the aim of every close-voter

Comment: @user486983 How many minds do you expect us to read, and for how long?  The OP has provided no information about their background, their English level, or (in fact) anything except a statement.  You've made some sweeping generalisations there, and while I understand where you're coming from I don't see how you can defend them.  My username is Latin; would you like to conclude that I'm a 2000-year old Roman?

Comment: @postmortes What do you do when you are a new member of a community where they don't speak your idiom? There is a high chance that you'll make mistakes (unintentionally), one way or another, even with assistance.

Comment: @user486983 personally I ask for help.  Which your OP has conspicuously not done.

Comment: @postmortes At least a minimum of 30 minutes, while OP checks the math.stack environment and gets familialized at least a bit. When you enter a totally new place, do you go there and exhibit your personal information? of course not. I defend OP because I can put myself in his place and see how would that be. //hmm maybe you have something to do with Latin roots

Comment: @user486983 turn that around: wouldn't it be reasonable to expect the OP to have taken that 30 minutes to take the tour, learn what is expected of a question here, and even prefix their question with "I'm new, my English is poor, if I make a mistake please help me understand why?"  We *do* see questions here with that kind of prefix, and the ones I've seen tend to get helpful comments at least initially.  Perhaps what I'm driving at here is why should the onus of effort be on the community and not the questioner? (And no, no Latin roots I'm afraid)

Comment: @postmortes I agree, but for some reason OP didn't take that path. This was a new user. Give them time and some of them will survive and become good contributors, some of them will not (even after long periods of time, they will never get it). Cut them their wings since the beginning and probably they won't come back ever again.

Comment: They do have time.  The Question is closed (placed "on-hold") pending improvements, which you may feel motivated to help the OP with.  It would not be clear to me what precisely the OP needs help with, but that's a good use to put the Comments below the existing Question.  I appreciate any efforts you can make to help them learn both the mathematics and the site practices.

Comment: I've triggered the "move to chat" warning so I think this will be my last comment:the same argument can be made for quickly closing and applying tough love.  Some people will respond well, others won't, and in both cases we'll lose some people who could have been great contributors.  Equally some people get run over by cars and killed before they can make their great contribution: that's the nature of the world we live in.

Comment: @postmortes On math.stack could be different. I mean it can be dependent or monitored, and not like an  _accident_ (like people run over by cars)

Comment: @hardmath You are right. I could have leave comments under OP's post.. but OP deleted their question.. why would that have happened? hmm.. strange.. maybe -4 downvotes helped?.. maybe the **Closed** helped...  maybe was a mistake..

Comment: Perhaps instead of asking that the community gives a user 30 minutes *after* posting their first question to "see how the site is like and adapt accordingly", perhaps, we want to hope that users spend an hour *before* their first post, trying to understand how the site works?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed (the question here on Meta, not the math question discussed in the post).  Regardless of what one thinks of the opinions expressed in it, how on earth is this question not on-topic here on Meta?

Comment: It's a Pavlov reaction @EricWofsey  . Closing questions on Meta and on SE. I do agree with OP. We should understand that new contributors dont know the rules. So for the mathjax..It's easier to edit the question and post a comment asking OP to learn a bit of Mathjax with the appropriate link to the tuto. That's more fair. And that's what most members do. They take on their time to edit the question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Of course, that would be better. But how to tell that to OP? One doesn't realize about their existence until they post their 1st question

Comment: @EricWofsey Indeed. It's absolutely nonsense & unfair what this users did to my post.

Comment: @LostInSpace Pavlov reaction?. \\ Yes I agree, sometimes one has to do "OP's work" so that they learn by one's example. Because being honest that MathJax tutorial at first glance looks kinda extreme for someone who has never seen those commands before

Comment: Thats what we say here when people react without thinking lol .... Many members have edited my answers so now I help as much as I can new contributors. I voted to reopen your post. We still need a single vote, I think.

Comment: @LostInSpace Ok. Thank you

Comment: I can't speak for the users who voted to close here, I wouldn't do that (even without my binding vote) as it *is* the meta site. But your question reads *a lot* like a rant, rather than raising and discussing an actual issue, and some people take issue with ranting.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Maybe you're right. But i think we should be a bit more friendly with new contributors. They are not supposed to know the rules. And for the format we are here to help improve the math formatting.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  "But your question reads a lot like a rant" Absolutely no. I don't know where does that come from, honestly. I think you're misunderstanding the _tone_ definitely. It was not nice that this happened within 5 minutes but that of course is far far away to say that is a _rant_ // Thank you for vote note, I know that with one of your votes it get automatically open/closed

Comment: The question you are referring to has been deleted since then.

Comment: @LostInSpace: To post a question, one has to register, and one has to jump through the hoops of a welcome page. One *can* choose to spend a few minutes looking at the site (just like one might look at StackOverflow and decide that's not the best place for a math question). It's hard for me to feel sympathy for people who do not find the energy to survey the land before building a house, and then finding themselves stuck in a bog.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  I understand what you mean Asaf.

Comment: @user486983: I think you underestimate how your question is read by some people. It complains about the treatment a new user has received, most of its screen real estate is a screenshot, and there are stars in the title trying to put emphasis. Not to mention that the question essentially reads as rhetoric, not as a genuine attempt for discussion.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you did read my question like a rant, then I am sorry for that (definitely not my intention). So my question would have been better without the screenshot?  also what's wrong with the stars, I thought looked better than this marks* and I wanted to make my title better to understand when reading it. ok, where is rhetoric? All that I have said in my question is what I saw on OP's. If you said it because of the part: (remember how lost one is in the first years) that is a true, that was true for me and for some of my colleagues. I don't see the wrongness by mentioning

Comment: @LostInSpace you said your -deleted question comment- to me right?  Well, I did notice the deletion of the question prior to your comment (see the prior comment where I pinged hardmath) but that was not quite the point of my post. The core point was the 5 minutes closure + newbie + blah blah..

Comment: My comment you mean ? @user486983 I was talking about the question that has been deleted since it's impossible to find it..

Comment: @LostInSpace This one: "The question you are referring to has been deleted since then."

Comment: I was talking about Broly-29 question @user486983 I just wanted to edit it and improve it but I could not find it

Comment: @LostInSpace Ok :). It turns out OP delete it himself.. but by then it was already edited by another user..

Comment: Ok I didn't know @user486983

Comment: One upside to closing very poor posts early is also that it prevents opportunistic answerers from answering the post until the post is improved and reopened.  I'd only support a thirty minute window for not closure if every post also prevented answers for 30 minutes.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You asked

> Is that  ok?

And the answer is

> Yes, it is fine

It's supported to **Close** 1st time psq   by 1st time users within **5** minutes (no more, ok? 5! :), regardless of their background.

(Psst btw nice new record: $-10$ downvotes in less than a day).

Comment: It's supported by some, and opposed by others. Also, I'm sure there have been questions here that got more downvotes faster (or maybe you just meant it was a personal record?).

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31135/why-is-this-question-completely-disappearing-where-i-have-answered-and-got-a-bou has 17 downvotes. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26352/should-we-eliminate-protecting has 19 downvotes. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30351/i-suggest-a-selectable-reason-for-a-down-up-vote-and-an-option-for-further-co has 15. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15050/blocking-favorite-unless-question-has-been-upvoted has 18. I'm sure the record is higher.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "It's supported by some, and opposed by others."  Ohh. oh ok. So let me put this straight, do you expect me to think that? seeing my question asked 22 hours ago with a record  of -10 downvotes + reading the comments where you can clearly see that the gist is no, no, no, no, no, no, no, yes, (no + saying that my question reads a _lot_ like a rant and essentially reads as rhetoric) +  the unfair and nonsensical action of closing my question  5 hours later after asking. It was open 4 hours later. It wasn't expected tbh, nor Eric's comments (I was surprised) that was a good to see.

Comment: Your question has 13 downvotes, and 4 upvotes. Four upvotes counts as "opposed by others". Four voters (other than yourself) voting to reopen the question counts as "opposed by others". Comments by users kludg and Eric and Lost count as "opposed by others". And when you look at the many times that *exactly* the issue you raise has been raised here in the past and hotly debated with users on both sides of the debate, you will see that it has been strongly opposed, by many others, on many occasions. Unfortunately, the supporters are currently ascendant (continued)

Comment: (continued), the opposition has lost hope and no longer rises to the bait the way it used to.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17353/what-does-a-new-user-have-to-do and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13016/too-quick-to-close are just questions *I* asked about treatment of new users. There are many more – it comes up every few months – there is support for both sides of the argument, but apparently more for the quickfire closers than for the time-to-breathers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I appreciate your comments trying to see the _nice_ side :3 where seems like doesn't exist. I can tell you that I perfectly understand the situation and also how things work

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I'd support a 30-minute "time to breathe", provided that applied to both a moratorium for thirty-minutes on (1) casting votes to close, *and* a moratorium for thirty-minutes (2)on answering the question.  There lies the rub.